# Add Online Image to Word Document Using OpenXml C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I found a way that can add Image from the local drive to a word document. my problem is that i need to add an online image uploaded to my server. my current app looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string document = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\hello.docx";
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\img.PNG";
        InsertAPicture(document, fileName);
    }

    public static void InsertAPicture(string document, string fileName)
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;

            ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                imagePart.FeedData(stream);
            }

            AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
        }
    }

    private static void AddImageToBody(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId)
    {
        // Define the reference of the image.
        var element =
             new Drawing(
                 new DW.Inline(
                     new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
                     new DW.EffectExtent()
                     {
                         LeftEdge = 0L,
                         TopEdge = 0L,
                         RightEdge = 0L,
                         BottomEdge = 0L
                     },
                     new DW.DocProperties()
                     {
                         Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                         Name = "Picture 1"
                     },
                     new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                         new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                     new A.Graphic(
                         new A.GraphicData(
                             new PIC.Picture(
                                 new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                     {

                                         Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                         Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                                     },
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                 new PIC.BlipFill(
                                     new A.Blip(
                                         new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                             new A.BlipExtension()
                                             {
                                                 Uri =
                                                    "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                             })
                                     )
                                     {
                                         Embed = relationshipId,
                                         CompressionState =
                                         A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                     },
                                     new A.Stretch(
                                         new A.FillRectangle())),
                                 new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                     new A.Transform2D(
                                         new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                         new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                     new A.PresetGeometry(
                                         new A.AdjustValueList()
                                     )
                                     { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                         )
                         { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                 )
                 {
                     DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     EditId = "50D07946"
                 });

        // Append the reference to body, the element should be in a Run.
        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
    }
```

How can I use this code or another code to add an online image instead of an image located on my computer. 
Code reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497430.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you download the image in a local temp folder, use it and word as local image and remove it, when no longer need it.
If this solution is not possible, I can suggest you to review this article (haven't tested it) [in memory image load](http://www.vcskicks.com/image-from-url.php).
Hope this helps.